# Redgate tool alternatives for maintaining and deploying oracle database changes

Tags: continuous-delivery, databases, toolchain

### In Short

We are currently searching for Redgate tool alternatives to maintain and deploy our database changes.

### What we have

- a big oracle database with many schemas (complex, strongly coupled)
- older Redgate Tools - Source Control (v5.x) and Schema Compare (latest v5.x and v6.x) for Oracle databases
- azure devops
- svn repository (containing lots of sql, pl/sql, and other things)

### How we currently work (simplified)

- our developers make DB changes (Oracle SQL and PL/SQL) inside their respective development database instances
- with Redgate Source Control the db changes get written into our repository (NOT as delta scripts like alter table scripts - instead the create table script gets replaced by an updated one)
- with Redgate Schema Compare the repo code and the deployment target db get compared - the result are deployment scripts (delta scripts, designed to update the deployment target db to the state of our repo content)
- we execute our scripts in the deployment target db

### Our current problems (only the relevant ones for this post)

- Redgate Source Control & Redgate Schema Compare make many mistakes especially with scheduler jobs - this way we can't really trust the tool (e.g.1 procedures that changed, don't get recognized as changed, e.g.2 grant statements on sys objects get created even though they shouldn't be)

### Sidenotes

- We have to refactor our processes as well, but this post is not about that
- We are currently evaluating the newer tool suite Redgate Flyway Enterprise
- At least in the near future we can't switch from an oracle db to another db -> thats why the tools have to work with oracle databases
- At least at the moment we don't plan to swith from a SVN repository to other ones
- We have to decouple and refactor our db content, but that will take time (multiple years) and is not the topic of this post

### Question

Do you have suggestions for Redgate tool alternatives, which:

- allow process automation (via azure devops pipelines)
- are reliably working with current verions of oracle databases
- allow to work in a similar process -> development in a dev db, then export into repository, then a deployment into target database (via pipeline)

Note: It can be multiple tools from different companies, as long as they work correctly.